# Didn't encrypt the whole folders and multiple files

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm developing an encryption/decrypt program and I did it. But I had an issue with it which I couldn't find it out. The problem is only one file will be encrypted at once not multiple. I tired to select multiple files but only encrypt the first file. And I could encrypt the whole folder as well. Need help in code. Can you tell me where is the problem in my following code?

```
private void encryptbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Title = "Encrypt To: ";
        sfd.Filter = "All Files(*.*)| *.*";
        sfd.FileName = "_ENC" + safepath;

        if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){


            if(pathtxt.Text != string.Empty){

                string inputFilePath = pathtxt.Text;

                string outputfilePath = sfd.FileName;

                string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
                using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
                {
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                    using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                int data;
                                while ((data = fsInput.ReadByte()) != -1)
                                {
                                    cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Encryption Successful");
                pathtxt.Text = string.Empty;
            }
```

Comment: 'string outputfilePath = sfd.FileName;' is for 1 file only. use `FuleNames` instead + loop

Comment: The problem is that your not looping through the files anywhere

Comment: what are you trying to do? encrypt a directory into a single flie? or one file per file in that directory? or encypt multiple files as selected in your dialog?

Comment: What i wanna to do just select any folder or files to encrypt them at any location on system. but m bit confused in my code

Comment: #Leonid Malyshev.. Acc to you i have to use fulenames and loop isn't work properly right ??

Comment: @singh I think he meant `FileNames`, but that property is pretty much useless in `SafeFileDialog` (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you only get the first file instead of multiple is because `SafeFileDialog` doesn't support multiple files (wouldn't make much sense, would it?).

Instead, you can specify multiple **input** files by either using all files in directory (Use a `FolderBrowserDialog` to select a directory and get all files with `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` or `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles`) or by specifying the files explicitly (use a `FileOpenDialog`, set `Multiselect = true` and use `FileNames`).

You can then automatically build your output file names with the various methods that `System.IO.Path` provides.

```
string sourceDirectory = @"C:\TestInput\";
string destinationDirectory = @"C:\TestOutput\";

// or with OpenFileDialog.FileNames
string[] inputFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory)

foreach(string inputfilePath in inputFiles)
{
    string outputfilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, 
        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(inputfilePath) + "_encrypted");

    //Encrypt here
}
```

Comment: The question was about multiply selection (I tired to select multiple files but only encrypt the first file) not all files in teh folder.

Comment: in most cases you should use EnumerateFiles not GetFiles, as enumerate allows background loading to continue while enumeration is being used

Comment: As mentionend in the Code Comment - OpenFileDialog.FileNames (with activated MultiSelect of course)

Comment: @MikeT Good point, but in this case I wanted to make sure the output is the same as `OpenFileDialog.FileNames` (`string[]`). OP obviously isn't very practiced in C# yet.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer the thing is multiple file has been selected but only dec the one file which is top position or 1st file only

Comment: @singh Because you are trying to specify multiple files when saving. SafeFileDialog doesn't allow that because it doesn't make any sense. How would you even know which input file should be saved to which output file?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer see multiselect= true;                                                      pathtxt.Text = string.Empty;
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

            dlg.Title = "Open File";
            dlg.Filter = "All Files(*.*)|*.*";

            dlg.Multiselect = true;
            dlg.CheckFileExists = true;
            dlg.CheckPathExists = true;

            if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){


                pathtxt.Text = dlg.FileName;
                safepath = dlg.SafeFileName;

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer i got it. i will replace it with folderBrowse

Comment: @singh That would be the best option. Regarding the code you just commented: That way you can only safe to an already existing file. And `SafeFileName` is not a `SaveFileName` (notice the `f` and `v` ?).

Answer (score 0):

I you want to loop through multiple files then there are several ways to do this

firstly with [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :note there are other OpenFileDialog's that have simlar functions but vary slightly on their details depending on if WPF, Siverlight, ASP.net, Winforms

this has a Multiselect and FileNames Property

if you use these then you can do

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog()
{
    Multiselect =true
};
if(open.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach(var file in open.FileNames )
    {
        Encypt(file);
    }
}
```

another choice would be to use a Directory

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirPath);

foreach(var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("Filter")
{
    Encypt(file);
}
```

you can get the dirpath from a [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are using winforms or any of the other similar dialogs, in your code you use `pathtxt.Text`

if you want to encrypt multiple files to a single file then i would suggest compressing them first and then encrypting the compressed stream as trying to separate the files back out when using multiple streams is very difficult